# T-SQL Multiple JOINS looking for NULL and data in specific column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This has been working flawlessly for what I intended. I am wanting to modify it, to be a little more useful. The additional data I need to retrieve is if "Test Date" is NULL, where the "Date Sampled" exceeds "Days" 29. The other columns that will then also show NULL values will be "Entered By", "TIN", and "Tested By".

I'll need to modify my 'Test Date' to show that if it's NULL, then it needs to get the current date, otherwise use the date present. The below is what I'd want it to look like when it returned data

EDIT: I apologize for my request being a little confusing. As requested, I'll do my best to break it down.

The code below is how my current query looks. I run this query to see which samples have been tested outside their specified time. The user will enter the date the sample was sampled. They will then say how many days they will be testing the sample. After testing the sample, they will put down the date the test was performed. They are allowed +/- 1 day. So, let's say they choose 28 days as how long it will take to perform the test. The Sampled it on October 26, 2017.  They perform their Test Performed date is on November 27, 2017. This sample was then tested at 32 days, outside of their 28 +/- 1 day. This will cause that sample to show up on my query.

What I did not account for is when a sample is to be broken at 28 days, and it's now 32 days and still not broken. What I need to do is look for when Test Performed Date has a NULL value, it should also show up on the list. However, I still need to know how many days the sample has been sitting, so I'll need to add the current date in the Test Performed Date.

My question is, how can I find all the NULL values that are in the Test Performed Date? Once I've found those NULLS, how can I put the current date in the Test Performed Date?

The table directly below, is what my query should be returning.

```
Cntrct  SMPL ID   SMPL Lvl  Days    DT SMPL    TST DT        Days CMPLT   ENTRD By  FCLTY ID    FCLTY NM    MNG DIST       TIN            TSTD By
Site1   180418      V        28    10/26/2017  11/27/2017         32      Jane Doe    I01010        Dummy Corp1   1       D4976943599   Jane Doe
Site2   101103      Q        28      5/9/2017    6/8/2017         30      Jacki Dbar  I01021        Dummy Corp2   1       L2010201034   Jeremy Lang
Site2   31393       Q        28     11/9/2016  11/22/2016         13      Chris Helms I01021        Dummy Corp2   1       L2010201034   Jeremy Lang
Site3   16031       V        28     10/4/2016   11/8/2016         35      John Doe    I07012        Dummy Corp3   7       H2019201020   Lisa Ho
Site3   47492       V        28     1/16/2017   2/15/2017         30      John Doe    I07012        Dummy Corp3   7       J7020020001   Michael Jackson
Site4   53652       Q        28     1/20/2017   3/27/2018         431       NULL      I01018        Dummy Corp4   1            NULL          NULL


/*
This query checks Projects and Laboratories managed by specified Districts,
to see if compressive strengths have been tested in their specified times. 
This report could be beneficial for both Lab IA Evaluations and MC Review.
*/

USE MACDWSQL1

SELECT DISTINCT
    C.CNTRT_ID AS Contract, 
    R.SMPL_NUM AS 'Sample ID', 
    S.SMPL_LVL_CD AS 'Sample Level',
    LEFT(R.VAL_NUM, LEN(R.VAL_NUM) -7) AS 'Days', 
    MAX(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)) AS 'Date Sampled',
    MAX(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)) AS 'Test Date', 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)), 
    MAX(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE))) AS 'Days Completed',
    RTRIM(U.[First Name])+' '+U.[Last Name] AS 'Entered By',
    L.FCLTY_ID AS 'Facility ID',
    Y.FCLTY_DS AS 'Facility Name',
    Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD AS 'Lab Managing District',
    V.TIN_ID AS 'TIN',
    RTRIM(V.FRST_NM) + ' ' + V.LAST_NM AS 'Tested By'
FROM 
    MACT103_TSTRSLTSTP R
INNER JOIN 
    MACT100_SMPL S ON S.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN 
    MACT102_TST_RSLT T ON T.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN 
    MACT066_PRDPRJSMPL P ON P.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN 
    MACT061_FINPROJ F ON     F.WPI_NUM + F.WPI_SEG_NUM + F.WP_PHAS_GRP_CD + F.WP_PHAS_TYP_CD + F.FINPROJ_SQ = P.WPI_NUM + P.WPI_SEG_NUM + P.WP_PHAS_GRP_CD + P.WP_PHAS_TYP_CD + P.FINPROJ_SQ
INNER JOIN 
    MACT106_SMPL_CNTRT C ON C.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN 
    MACT101_SMPLROUTE E ON E.SMPL_NUM = S.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN 
    MACT078_LAB L ON L.FCLTY_SQ = E.FCLTY_SQ
INNER JOIN 
    MACT070_FCLTY Y ON Y.FCLTY_SQ = E.FCLTY_SQ
INNER JOIN 
    macvw0001_mac_user U ON U.MAC_USER_SQ = T.UPDT_USER_SQ
INNER JOIN 
    MACT322_TECH H ON H.PERS_SQ = T.PERS_SQ
INNER JOIN 
    MACT401_RDVCT_PERS V ON V.RED_VECTOR_NUM = H.RED_VECTOR_NUM
WHERE 
    T.TST_DFIN_ID = 'C39' -- This only looking at C39 tests
    AND S.SPEC_SQ <> '29' -- Excludes Material 457 - Integral Pile Jackets  
    AND S.SMPL_LVL_CD IN ('V','Q') -- This is looking only for V and Q samples.  If you want it to look for R samples, add ,'RT' within the parenthesis.
    AND S.SPEC_CLSF_CD = '1' -- The 1 designates it's a Project sample, 2 would be for Program samples, and 3 Research samples.
    AND R.VAL_TXT = 'Days'
    AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, S.SMPL_DT, T.TST_PERF_DT) > R.VAL_NUM + 1 -- 28 days, + 1 day (cannot assign 22 hours)
         OR 
         DATEDIFF(DAY, S.SMPL_DT, T.TST_PERF_DT) < R.VAL_NUM - 1 -- 28 days, - 1 day (cannot assign 22 hours)
    )
AND (F.MNG_DIST_CD IN ('01', '07') -- This designates which District the project is in.
     OR Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD IN ('01', '07') -- This designates which District the Lab is under.
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT M.PMCL_LETR_SQ
                FROM MACT430_PMCL_LTR M
                WHERE M.CNTRT_ID = C.CNTRT_ID -- This excludes Contracts where the PMCL letter was issued.
               )
    OR T.TST_PERF_DT IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    R.SMPL_NUM,R.VAL_NUM ,R.VAL_TXT, C.CNTRT_ID, L.FCLTY_ID, Y.FCLTY_DS, 
    S.SMPL_LVL_CD, U.[First Name], U.[Last Name], Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD, V.TIN_ID, V.FRST_NM, V.LAST_NM
ORDER BY 
    'Facility Name', 'Facility ID', C.CNTRT_ID, 'Days Completed'  DESC
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: For our (mine at least) benefit could you break down your request into a few separate sections. As it reads now it feels like a run-on sentence and is hard to parse.Could you 1) describe you table/data structure, 2) describe what your current query does, 3) say how you would like it to differ from the current results.

Comment: Start with `having Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)) is null;`

Comment: I have edited my initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** This iteration is working as I intended.

```
USE MACDWSQL1

SELECT 
  S.Contract, 
  S.[Sample ID],
  S.[Sample Level],
  S.Days,
  S.[Date Sampled],
  S.[Test Date],
  S.[Days Completed],
  S.[Entered By],
  S.[Facility ID],
  S.[Facility Name],
  S.[Lab Managing District],
  S.TIN,
  S.[Tested By]
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    C.CNTRT_ID AS Contract, 
    R.SMPL_NUM AS 'Sample ID', 
    S.SMPL_LVL_CD AS 'Sample Level',
    LEFT(R.VAL_NUM, LEN(R.VAL_NUM) -7) AS 'Days', 
    Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)) AS 'Date Sampled',
    iif (T.TST_PERF_DT IS NULL,CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE) ,Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE))) AS 'Test Date', 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)),
    iif (T.TST_PERF_DT IS NULL,CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE) ,Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)))) AS 'Days Completed',
    RTRIM(U.[First Name])+' '+U.[Last Name] AS 'Entered By',
    L.FCLTY_ID AS 'Facility ID',
    Y.FCLTY_DS AS 'Facility Name',
    Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD AS 'Lab Managing District',
    V.TIN_ID AS 'TIN',
    RTRIM(V.FRST_NM)+' '+V.LAST_NM AS 'Tested By'
FROM MACT102_TST_RSLT T

    INNER JOIN MACT103_TSTRSLTSTP R ON T.SMPL_NUM=R.SMPL_NUM 
    INNER JOIN MACT100_SMPL S ON S.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
    INNER JOIN MACT106_SMPL_CNTRT AS c  ON C.SMPL_NUM = T.SMPL_NUM
    INNER JOIN MACT101_SMPLROUTE E ON E.SMPL_NUM = S.SMPL_NUM
    INNER JOIN MACT066_PRDPRJSMPL P ON P.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
    INNER JOIN MACT061_FINPROJ F ON F.WPI_NUM+F.WPI_SEG_NUM+F.WP_PHAS_GRP_CD+F.WP_PHAS_TYP_CD+F.FINPROJ_SQ
                = P.WPI_NUM+P.WPI_SEG_NUM+P.WP_PHAS_GRP_CD+P.WP_PHAS_TYP_CD+P.FINPROJ_SQ
    INNER JOIN MACT078_LAB L ON L.FCLTY_SQ = E.FCLTY_SQ
    INNER JOIN MACT070_FCLTY Y ON Y.FCLTY_SQ = E.FCLTY_SQ
    INNER JOIN macvw0001_mac_user U ON U.MAC_USER_SQ = T.UPDT_USER_SQ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MACT322_TECH H ON H.PERS_SQ = T.PERS_SQ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MACT401_RDVCT_PERS V ON V.RED_VECTOR_NUM = H.RED_VECTOR_NUM

WHERE T.TST_DFIN_ID = 'C39' -- This only looking at C39 tests
   AND S.SPEC_SQ <> '29' -- Excludes Material 457 - Integral Pile Jackets  
   AND S.SMPL_LVL_CD IN ('V','Q') -- This is looking only for V and Q samples.  If you want it to look for R samples, add ,'RT' within the parenthesis.
   AND S.SPEC_CLSF_CD = '1' -- The 1 designates it's a Project sample, 2 would be for Program samples, and 3 Research samples.
   AND (R.VAL_TXT in ( 'Days') OR (R.VAL_NUM IS NULL AND R.VAL_TXT IS NULL)) 
   AND (
       DATEDIFF(DAY,T.TST_PERF_DT,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 -- This looks for samples tested within the past 90 days
       OR 
       DATEDIFF(DAY,S.SMPL_DT,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 -- This looks for samples sampled within the past 90 days
       )
   AND (
       DATEDIFF(DAY, S.SMPL_DT, T.TST_PERF_DT) > R.VAL_NUM + 1 -- 28 days, + 1 day (cannot assign 22 hours)
       OR     
       DATEDIFF(DAY, S.SMPL_DT, T.TST_PERF_DT) < R.VAL_NUM - 1 -- 28 days, - 1 day (cannot assign 22 hours)
   OR T.TST_PERF_DT IS NULL
       )
   AND (
       F.MNG_DIST_CD IN ('01', '07') -- This designates which District the project is in.
       OR
       Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD IN ('01', '07') -- This designates which District the Lab is under.
       )
   AND NOT EXISTS 
       (
       SELECT M.PMCL_LETR_SQ
       FROM MACT430_PMCL_LTR M
       WHERE M.CNTRT_ID = C.CNTRT_ID -- This excludes Contracts where the PMCL letter was issued.
       )

GROUP BY R.SMPL_NUM,R.VAL_NUM ,R.VAL_TXT, C.CNTRT_ID, L.FCLTY_ID, Y.FCLTY_DS, S.SMPL_LVL_CD, U.[First Name], 
    U.[Last Name], Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD, V.TIN_ID, V.FRST_NM, V.LAST_NM,T.TST_PERF_DT 
) AS S

WHERE ((S.Days IS NULL) AND (S.[Days Completed] > 29)) 
    OR ((NOT (S.Days IS NULL)) AND ((S.[Days Completed] <= S.[Days] -1) OR (S.[Days Completed] >= S.[Days] +1)))


ORDER BY S.[Facility Name] , S.[Facility ID], S.Contract, S.[Days Completed]  DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it

```
having Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)) is null 
   and Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)) > Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)))
```

Comment: Thanks paparazzo.  That didn't work.  It returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question. It is not obvious what you are looking for.
As I understand you want to set the current date if the test date is null. In this case you can use [coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql). Coalesce returns the value of the first argument which is not null.

Answer (score 0):

The query seems to work 'almost' well, you just have to use a couple of `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Simply use

```
ISNULL(Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)), GETDATE())
```

instead of

```
Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE))
```

And for the float days use `CAST` to `INT`, so the select will look like:

```
SELECT 
C.CNTRT_ID AS Contract, 
R.SMPL_NUM AS 'Sample ID', 
S.SMPL_LVL_CD AS 'Sample Level',
CAST(R.VAL_NUM AS INT) AS 'Days', 
Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)) AS 'Date Sampled',
ISNULL(Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)), GETDATE()) AS 'Test Date', 
DATEDIFF(DAY, Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)), ISNULL(Max(CAST(T.TST_PERF_DT AS DATE)), GETDATE())) AS 'Days Completed'
...
```

Try to change these two joins using `LEFT` instead of `INNER`:

```
LEFT JOIN macvw0001_mac_user U ON U.MAC_USER_SQ = T.UPDT_USER_SQ
LEFT JOIN MACT401_RDVCT_PERS V ON V.RED_VECTOR_NUM = H.RED_VECTOR_NUM
```

Also you can delete `R.VAL_TXT` from your `GROUP BY` it is useless

Finally the `ORDER BY`, in T-SQL you cant use alias to specify columns, but you can use indexes:

```
ORDER BY Y.FCLTY_DS, L.FCLTY_ID, C.CNTRT_ID, 7 DESC
```

In my tests I have considered `R.VAL_NUM` as an integer column with the number of days choosen for how long it will take to perform the test, but I have not understood the reason why you treat it as a text string in your select `LEFT(R.VAL_NUM, LEN(R.VAL_NUM) -7)`,
can you explain this?

**EDIT:**

I have added a sub query (CTE) on `MACT102_TST_RSLT` for greater readability.
Your final query should be something like that:

```
;WITH
T as (
    select *
    , CAST(ISNULL(cast(TST_PERF_DT as date), GETDATE()) AS DATE) [Test Date] 
    from MACT102_TST_RSLT
)
SELECT 
    C.CNTRT_ID AS Contract, 
    R.SMPL_NUM AS [Sample ID], 
    S.SMPL_LVL_CD AS [Sample Level],
    CAST(R.VAL_NUM AS INT) AS [Days], 
    Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)) AS [Date Sampled],
    Max([Test Date]) [Test Date], 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, Max(CAST(S.SMPL_DT AS DATE)), max([Test Date])) AS [Days Completed],
    RTRIM(U.[First Name])+' '+U.[Last Name] AS [Entered By],
    L.FCLTY_ID AS [Facility ID],
    Y.FCLTY_DS AS [Facility Name], 
    Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD AS [Lab Managing District],
    V.TIN_ID AS [TIN],
    RTRIM(V.FRST_NM)+' '+V.LAST_NM AS [Tested By]
FROM MACT103_TSTRSLTSTP R
INNER JOIN MACT100_SMPL S ON S.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN  T ON T.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN MACT066_PRDPRJSMPL P ON P.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN MACT061_FINPROJ F ON F.WPI_NUM + F.WPI_SEG_NUM + F.WP_PHAS_GRP_CD + F.WP_PHAS_TYP_CD + F.FINPROJ_SQ = P.WPI_NUM + P.WPI_SEG_NUM + P.WP_PHAS_GRP_CD + P.WP_PHAS_TYP_CD + P.FINPROJ_SQ
INNER JOIN MACT106_SMPL_CNTRT C ON C.SMPL_NUM = R.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN MACT101_SMPLROUTE E ON E.SMPL_NUM = S.SMPL_NUM
INNER JOIN MACT078_LAB L ON L.FCLTY_SQ = E.FCLTY_SQ
INNER JOIN MACT070_FCLTY Y ON Y.FCLTY_SQ = E.FCLTY_SQ
LEFT JOIN macvw0001_mac_user U ON U.MAC_USER_SQ = T.UPDT_USER_SQ
INNER JOIN MACT322_TECH H ON H.PERS_SQ = T.PERS_SQ
LEFT JOIN MACT401_RDVCT_PERS V ON V.RED_VECTOR_NUM = H.RED_VECTOR_NUM
WHERE 1=1
AND T.TST_DFIN_ID = 'C39' -- This only looking at C39 tests
AND S.SPEC_SQ <> '29' -- Excludes Material 457 - Integral Pile Jackets  
AND S.SMPL_LVL_CD IN ('V','Q') -- This is looking only for V and Q samples.  If you want it to look for R samples, add ,'RT' within the parenthesis.
AND S.SPEC_CLSF_CD = '1' -- The 1 designates it's a Project sample, 2 would be for Program samples, and 3 Research samples.
AND R.VAL_TXT = 'Days'
AND (ABS(R.VAL_NUM - DATEDIFF(DAY, S.SMPL_DT, T.[Test Date])) > 1) -- 28 days, +/- 1 day (cannot assign 22 hours)
AND (
    F.MNG_DIST_CD IN ('01', '07') -- This designates which District the project is in.
    OR
    Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD IN ('01', '07') -- This designates which District the Lab is under.
    )
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT M.PMCL_LETR_SQ
        FROM MACT430_PMCL_LTR M
        WHERE M.CNTRT_ID = C.CNTRT_ID -- This excludes Contracts where the PMCL letter was issued.
    )
GROUP BY R.SMPL_NUM,R.VAL_NUM , C.CNTRT_ID, L.FCLTY_ID, Y.FCLTY_DS, S.SMPL_LVL_CD, U.[First Name], U.[Last Name], Y.FDOT_MNG_DIST_CD, V.TIN_ID, V.FRST_NM, V.LAST_NM
ORDER BY Y.FCLTY_DS, L.FCLTY_ID, C.CNTRT_ID, 7 DESC
```

Try it AS-IS and let me know.

Comment: This was a decimal.  I was trying to remove the decimal and the zeros after it.

I have run the code above, and it's still not showing when I have NULL values for TST_PERF_DT

Comment: Still not showing the NULLs.  I do have it working though.  I'll update my post.

Comment: you have changed the wrong JOIN's the right ones were on `macvw0001_mac_user` and `MACT401_RDVCT_PERS` tables you have changed the one on `MACT322_TECH`

Comment: I have ran the updated query above, and it's still not giving me the NULLS.  I have updated my query above, with what I have done to get it to work correctly.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: `[Entered By]` is from table `macvw0001_mac_user` with your `INNER JOIN` you will never get NULLS in that column, because you will filter out the row. Also, your updated query is the same of mine, if you have solved it putting a `LEFT JOIN` also on `MACT322_TECH` it means my answer was correct and you should accept it

Comment: I've tried your code, switching out the JOINs, and it's still not returning the NULLS.

Comment: have you tried it complete? or you have tried to apply some update to your? I would be very curious to see your test data..

Comment: I have tried it, without applying some of my updates.  Explain what you mean you'd like to see my test data?  My table data, or my returned query results?

Comment: please take a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/10115), I have prepared a test field for the query. it is working, if something is wrong with data I have used, update it and then post the updated link (it change each time you run the query)